# Как получить индекс последнего элемента помещающегося на экране?

Tags: java, android

Нашел как это сделать, в активности или фрагменте, когда мы создаем manager, а вот как это сделать внутри адаптера RecyclerView не нашел. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @pavlofff RecyclerVIew

Answer (score 1):

Первый / последний видимый элемент зависит от вашего  `LayoutManager`. Если вы используете `LinearLayoutManager` или `GridLayoutManager`, можете использоваться:

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Например:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

[Мой ответ - перевод ответ с англ. темы на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview)

Comment: Ну LayoutManager у меня в активности, а не адаптере

Comment: А кто вам мешает организовать доступ из Адаптера к LayoutManager?

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Решение в лоб - передать ссылку на него в конструкторе